# CanJS - correct way to pass a callback from the viewmodel to the stache file

Tags: canjs, canjs-view, canjs-control, donejs, canjs-component

I have an old **CanJS** component which is renders a **React** component, and where now I need to pass a callback.

I found a way to pass the callback but I feel it's not the best way because in some cases it seems that the *viewmodel* reference is not the same and therefore some properties are not updated correctly in some moments.

**My CanJS component - *viewmodel*:**

```
export default DefineMap.extend("StoreVM", {

  pencils: {
    Type: DefineList.extend({
      '#': "number",
      hasStock() {
        return this.every(i => i > 0);
      }
    }),
    default() {
      return [60, 5, 30];
    }
  },

  handleProductStockChange: {
    value() {
      const onStockChange = (amount) => {
        this.pencils[2] = amount;
        this.onPencilsStockChange && this.onPencilsStockChange(this.pencils.hasStock());
      };
      return onStockChange.bind(this);
    }
  }
});
```

**My CanJS component - *stache*:**

```
<can-import from="pm-gui/components/pencils"/>

<store-pencils onStockChange:from="handleProductStockChange" />
```

Initially I was trying to implement the callback this way:

```
handleProductStockChange (amount) => {
  this.pencils[2] = amount;
  this.onPencilsStockChange && this.onPencilsStockChange(this.pencils.hasStock());
},
```

However the '*this*' reference doesn't exist if I do the method this way.

What is the correct way to define the callback in the *viewmodel*?

I don't find anything helpful in the CanJs documentation about this.

**CanJs versions in use:**

```
"can-component": "^5.0.0",
"can-connect": "^4.0.1",
"can-construct": "^3.5.6",
"can-construct-super": "^3.2.1",
"can-control": "^5.0.1",
"can-debug": "^2.0.7",
"can-define": "^2.8.0",
"can-define-backup": "^2.1.2",
"can-deparam": "^1.2.2",
"can-diff": "1.5.0",
"can-dom-data": "^1.0.3",
"can-dom-events": "^1.3.11",
"can-dom-mutate": "^2.0.9",
"can-key": "^1.2.1",
"can-list": "^4.2.3",
"can-log": "^1.0.2",
"can-map": "^4.3.15",
"can-map-define": "^4.4.0",
"can-model": "^4.1.0",
"can-observable-array": "^1.1.4",
"can-observable-object": "^1.1.4",
"can-observation": "^4.2.0",
"can-param": "^1.1.3",
"can-query-logic": "^1.2.2",
"can-queues": "^1.3.2",
"can-react-component": "^3.0.0",
"can-reflect": "^1.18.0",
"can-set-legacy": "^1.0.1",
"can-stache": "^5.1.1",
"can-stache-bindings": "^5.0.5",
"can-stache-converters": "^5.0.0",
"can-stache-element": "^1.2.0",
"can-symbol": "^1.6.5",
"can-type": "^1.1.6",
"can-types": "^1.4.0",
"can-util": "^3.14.0",
"can-view-autorender": "^6.0.0",
"can-view-callbacks": "^5.0.0",
"can-view-model": "^4.0.3",
```

Comment: Can you precise the used Canjs version?

Comment: @CherifBOUCHELAGHEM I updated my question to include the version